# How to reduce the space between the author block and paper text? sig-alternate.cls

Tags: spacing, titles

I am using the template [`sig-alternate.cls`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls), but I find that the space between the author block and the paper text is too large, how can I reduce this space?

Edit: I want to reduce the space between the author block and the paper text.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\begin{document} 
\title{shrink space}
\author{XXX}
\maketitle
paper text here!
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please provide a link to the file `sig-alternate.cls`.

Comment: It's here http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your document class defines the command `\@maketitle` with an extra vertical skip. Use the following definition to reduce the space:

```
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \setbox\@acmtitlebox\vbox{%
\baselineskip 20pt
\vskip 2em                   % Vertical space above title.
   \begin{center}
    {\ttlfnt \@title\par}       % Title set in 18pt Helvetica (Arial) bold size.
    \vskip 1.5em                % Vertical space after title.
%This should be the subtitle.
{\subttlfnt \the\subtitletext\par}\vskip 1.25em%\fi
    {\baselineskip 16pt\aufnt   % each author set in \12 pt Arial, in a
     \lineskip .5em             % tabular environment
     \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author
     \end{tabular}\par}
    \vskip 1.5em               % Vertical space after author.
   \end{center}}
 \dimen0=\ht\@acmtitlebox
% \advance\dimen0 by -12.75pc\relax % comment by Marco Daniel
 \unvbox\@acmtitlebox
 \ifdim\dimen0<0.0pt\relax\vskip-\dimen0\fi}
```

---

Without the modification:
[image]

With the modification:

[image]

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \setbox\@acmtitlebox\vbox{%
\baselineskip 20pt
\vskip 2em                   % Vertical space above title.
   \begin{center}
    {\ttlfnt \@title\par}       % Title set in 18pt Helvetica (Arial) bold size.
    \vskip 1.5em                % Vertical space after title.
%This should be the subtitle.
{\subttlfnt \the\subtitletext\par}\vskip 1.25em%\fi
    {\baselineskip 16pt\aufnt   % each author set in \12 pt Arial, in a
     \lineskip .5em             % tabular environment
     \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author
     \end{tabular}\par}
    \vskip 1.5em               % Vertical space after author.
   \end{center}}
 \dimen0=\ht\@acmtitlebox
% \advance\dimen0 by -12.75pc\relax % comment by Marco Daniel
 \unvbox\@acmtitlebox
 \ifdim\dimen0<0.0pt\relax\vskip-\dimen0\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\title{shrink space}
\author{XXX}
\maketitle
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I directly commented the line in the sig-alternate.cls file. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! I am now wanting to use a smaller font for the reference section, by what means can I implement that then?

Comment: @Bloodmoon: You should ask a new follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following method is a more direct way: comment out this line in the sig-alternate.cls.

```
\advance\dimen0 by -12.75pc\relax % Increased space for title box -- KBT
```

This line is in the definition of `\@maketitle`, and is meant to increase the space between the author block and paper text.