# Smaller font for the reference section

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize, templates

This is a follow up question to [How to reduce the space between the author block and paper text? sig-alternate.cls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57505/how-to-reduce-the-space-between-the-author-block-and-paper-text-sig-alternate-c)

I am using the template `sig-alternate.cls`, but I need a smaller font size for the reference section, how can I get that?

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\bibliography{sigproc}
```

Comment: If you indent the code lines with 4 spaces, it will be displayed as such. Also, we usually don't greet or thank other forum members, not out of rudeness, but because we intend to focus on the actual question. `:)`

Comment: The font is defined with `\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 12pt}` So you have to change this.

Comment: @Count Zero, thanks for your comment. I don't think my gratitude to other forum members bring anything harmful, nor will it distract our attention on the question itself. Moreover, the forum member that receives the gratitudes will be more willing to answer questions, which will make our forum better. So thank you again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reduce the font size for the whole "References" section (not only for its heading), you may use the `etoolbox` package to add `\small` or `\scriptsize` to the definition of the `thebibliography` environment. (`\footnotesize` won't do any good, because its definition in `sig-alternate.cls` resembles that of `\normalsize`.)

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\scriptsize}{}{}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01}.

\let\secfnt\undefined
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 10pt}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, this is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 4):

The font of the section is defined by

```
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 12pt}
```

So to change it in front of the bibliography use:

```
\let\secfnt\undefined
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 10pt}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc}
```

If the bibliography isn't the last section you should group the redefinition:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sigproc.bib}
@book{test,
author={Any Body},
title={Some Title},
year={2012},
puplisher={here}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document} 
paper text here!
\cite{test}
\let\secfnt\undefined
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 10pt}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc}
\end{document}
```

Please provide always Minimal Working examples.

Comment: The way that class sets the fonts is completely wrong!

Comment: I tried Daniel's method, but it only reduce the font of the "REFERENCE" title, the references are of the same font.

Comment: @Bloodmoon: Indeed. I understood this question in this way.

Comment: In fact, I mean how to reduce the font of the reference SECTION, not only the title. Do you have any idea? Thanks!